# VueJS pass parameters through the router next()

Tags: vue.js, parameters, vuejs2, vue-router

I want to pass the last route into my router when I'm in /login to redirect the user when is logged to desired route.

So the user go to `/payment` I redirect to `/login` and when the authentication is ok I want to redirect the user to `payement`

Here is my router.js :

```
import ...

Vue.use(Router)

let router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      component: About
    },
    {
      path: '/payment',
      name: 'payment',
      component: Payment,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/my-account',
      name: 'my-account',
      component: MyAccount,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log('Before Each Routes')
  if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
      console.log('Logged in')
      next()
      return
    }
    console.log(to.fullPath)
    next({
      path: '/login',
      params: { nextUrl: to.fullPath }
    })
    return
  } else {
    console.log(to.fullPath)
    next()
  }
})

export default router
```

So I set some console.log and I got this :

if I go directly to /login, Output :

```
Before Each Routes
/login
```

Then if I go to /payment, Output :

```
Before Each Routes
/payment
Before Each Routes
/login
```

So now when I go in my login component and I use `this.$route.params.nextUrl` it's undefined. The `next()` parameter doesn't exist and I don't know why.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing two different mechanisms: params and query. Params have to be integral to the url, like `/user/:id` while query params are appended automatically.

You want this:

```
next({
    path: '/login',
    query: {
       nextUrl: to.fullPath,
    }
})
```

Related reading: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties

Comment: I have almost the exact same issue but with twist; The vue-router docs advise against coupling components to the router via the `this.$router.blah` pattern and suggest passing props instead.  This doesn't seem to work for the query part of the URL. I've tried everything  I can't seem figure out how to pass query parameters to components.

Answer (score 10):

Tristan's approach above is the best when passing a url as a parameter. However, in normal cases we're passing something like an id so you can use this:

```
next({ name: 'account', params: { id: 3 } });
```

Add the replace option to prevent the navigation from appearing in the history:

```
next({ name: 'account', params: { id: 3 }, replace: true });
```

I'm using vue-router 3.1.6.